# What constitutes a player as a rookie?

Tags: terminology, major-leagues

When is a player said to be a **rookie** in North American major league sports? My understanding is that a rookie is a player that is playing his first professional season. But for how long is that player considered to be a rookie?

I have heard many times a player being discussed as a rookie even though he was in his second year. So is a player called a rookie only in the season he starts (I don't believe that's the case), or until he has played as many games as there in a full season, or for some other length of time?

Answer (score 2):

The rookie status varies between different sports.

**In the [MLB](http://mlb.mlb.com/mlb/official_info/about_mlb/rules_regulations.jsp):**

> **Determining rookie status:**
>
> A player shall be considered a rookie unless, during a previous season or seasons, he has (a) exceeded 130
>   at-bats or 50 innings pitched in the Major Leagues; or (b) accumulated
>   more than 45 days on the active roster of a Major League club or clubs
>   during the period of 25-player limit (excluding time in the military
>   service and time on the disabled list).

So in Baseball it is possible to be considered a rookie in your 2nd season or even later, if injuries or other things prevent you from being on the active roster long enough.

---

**The NFL** uses the term just as you said, but has no definition in the rules. [Here](https://www.sportingcharts.com/dictionary/nfl/rookie.aspx) is a small statement about it.

> **What is Rookie?**
>
> This is a term used in most every sport at every level of competition,
>   NFL football included, to refer to a **first year player**. In the
>   National Football League, a first year player may be acquired through
>   the NFL Draft or as a free-agent if they went undrafted. (...) A rookie is not necessarily young,
>   though this is usually the case. If a player has never played NFL
>   football before, they are considered a rookie, despite their age. (...)

---

**The NBA** does the [same](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rookie):

> In the National Basketball Association, a rookie is any player who has
>   never played a game in the NBA until that year.

---

**The MLS** is different again and a rookie is someone with no prior professional experience ([Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MLS_Rookie_of_the_Year_Award)).

> MLS, as opposed to other American sports leagues like Major League
>   Baseball, only designates a player as a rookie if the player has had
>   no prior professional experience. So, for example, although Taylor
>   Twellman finished second in MVP voting in 2002, he was ineligible for
>   the Rookie of the Year Award because he had played on the reserve team
>   of 1860 Munich.

(I don't know why he was ineligible, because 1860 Munich II played in the Regionalliga at this time, which is not a professional league (3rd division at this time) and he never played for the Bundesliga team of 1860 Munich)

---

**In the NHL** the [rules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calder_Memorial_Trophy) are pretty strict, because they take any major professional league into account and not just Ice Hockey.

> To be eligible for the award, a player cannot have played any more
>   than 25 regular season games previously in any single season, nor have
>   played in more than six regular season games in each of two separate
>   preceding seasons in any major professional league.

Comment: Great answer. One controversy with the NHL is that they don't consider the KHL a major professional league. Artemi Panarin famously won the Rookie of the Year award in 2016, despite playing professional hockey in the KHL for ~6 years before coming to the NHL.