# Do postseason games count against the NHL games played limit for rookie status?

Tags: rules, ice-hockey, nhl, postseason, rookie

Adding to the question [here](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/18168/what-constitutes-a-player-as-a-rookie), do NHL postseason games count towards the current 25 game limit for a player to maintain rookie status?

The wording of the current [NHL rules](https://www.nhl.com/info/hockey-operations-guidelines#rookie) seem a bit ambiguous as to whether a young player called up for the Stanley Cup playoffs would still maintain rookie status if he played 28 post season games, but no regular season games. The rules quote:

> To be considered a rookie, a player must not have played in more than 25 NHL games in any preceding seasons, nor in six or more NHL games in each of any two preceding seasons. Any player at least 26 years of age (by September 15th of that season) is not considered a rookie.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, postseason games do not count for rookie eligibility.

For example, Matt Murray [was eligible to be considered for the Calder Trophy in 2017, the year after he won the Stanley Cup](https://www.sbnation.com/nhl/2016/11/29/13776546/matt-murray-penguins-calder-trophy-nhl-awards), despite playing 13 regular season games and 21 postseason games in 2015-2016. He did not win it, instead [finishing fourth](https://www.hockey-reference.com/awards/voting-2017.html), but was named to the [NHL All-Rookie team](https://www.nhl.com/player/matt-murray-8476899) in 2017.